# Tornado coroutines don’t work in Cython

Tags: python, generator, tornado, cython, coroutine

This code works in Python 3.4.3 using Tornado 4.1 — it sleeps for 1 second and then prints "Hello World! 123". But when compiled using Cython (I tried versions 0.20.1post0 and 0.23dev), it does nothing.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import datetime
from tornado import gen

@gen.coroutine
def test():
    yield gen.Task(ioloop.add_timeout, datetime.timedelta(seconds=1))
    return 123

@gen.coroutine
def hello_world():
    print('Hello World! {}'.format((yield test())))

ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop().instance()
ioloop.run_sync(hello_world)
```

Commands I used to build and run Cython version:

```
cython --embed -o hello.c hello.py
gcc -shared -fPIC -O0 -Wall -I/usr/include/python3.4 -o hello.so hello.c
python -c 'import hello'
```

Comment: There are plenty bug reports around relating to cython and coroutines, this is more than likely another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Cython coroutines are natively supported beginning with Tornado 4.3. The workaround below is only for older versions of Tornado.

---

Tornado coroutines are not currently supported with Cython. The main problem is that a generator compiled by Cython does not pass `isinstance(types.GeneratorType)` (and last time I looked there was no other class that could be used instead).

The best fix for this would be a change to Cython to add a common base class for generators, but as a quick hack I've had some success with this patch to `tornado/gen.py`:

```
diff --git a/tornado/gen.py b/tornado/gen.py
index aa931b4..b348f21 100644
--- a/tornado/gen.py
+++ b/tornado/gen.py
@@ -91,6 +91,12 @@ from tornado.concurrent import Future, TracebackFuture
 from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
 from tornado.stack_context import ExceptionStackContext, wrap

+def _is_generator(obj):
+    # cython generates a new generator type for each module without a
+    # common base class :(
+    return (isinstance(obj, types.GeneratorType) or
+            str(type(obj)) == "<type 'generator'>")
+

 class KeyReuseError(Exception):
     pass
@@ -147,7 +153,7 @@ def engine(func):
             except (Return, StopIteration) as e:
                 result = getattr(e, 'value', None)
             else:
-                if isinstance(result, types.GeneratorType):
+                if _is_generator(result):
                     def final_callback(value):
                         if value is not None:
                             raise ReturnValueIgnoredError(
@@ -219,7 +225,7 @@ def coroutine(func):
                 future.set_exc_info(sys.exc_info())
                 return future
             else:
-                if isinstance(result, types.GeneratorType):
+                if _is_generator(result):
                     def final_callback(value):
                         deactivate()
                         future.set_result(value)
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Btw, it should be `"<class 'generator'>"` for Python 3.

Comment: Hah, Twisted does the same, and I made a similar hack there when I used it.